# Can I repair my system disk (10.6) by booting off a 10.5 install CD?

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I'm running Snow Leopard (10.6) and OnyX told me I need to boot from my install CD and use Disk Utility to repair my drive. (It wasn't any more specific as to what the actual problem was.) I can't find my Snow Leopard disc anywhere, but I've got a 10.5.8 disc here. Will it work too?

(Just to be clear, I'm talking about a filesystem repair, not a permission repair. Repairing permissions with a Disk Utility from an older version of the OS won't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can boot from the Leopard disc, it should work.

You can boot from the install disc by holding <kbd>C</kbd> during boot.

Comment: Depend what you mean by work - the disk level stuff maybe but permissions no

Comment: All I needed to do was run the filesystem checks, not repair permissions, and it worked fine. (I didn't try verifying/repairing permissions at all, so I have no idea if that would have worked.)

Comment: @Mark: true, but the permissions repair portion is best run from the live system anyway; I doubt Onyx would've recommended booting from DVD for a permissions repair.  BTW, I'm leery of using 10.5's filesystem repair on 10.6, because Apple added at least one feature filesystem-level compression) to 10.6 that 10.5 and its repair tool won't understand.

Comment: The filesystem compression (if I believe) uses a file system fork (like the data/resource forks), so 10.5 should support it as just another file fork.

Comment: @Gordon: I did a filesystem repair with 10.5's Disk Utility and it didn't complain about [any of my compressed files](http://clustersapp.com/), so I believe @CajunLuke is right.

Comment: @CajunLuke @Brant: This falls into the general category of things that *should* work, but...  And when it comes to things like filesystem repair, I prefer to err on the side of paranoia.  Anyway, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot into Snow Leopard at all?  If you can, try this command from terminal:

`sudo diskutil repairPermissions /`

Broken down this does the following:

- `sudo` - run this command as superuser/admin
- `diskutil` - run the `diskutil` program
- `repairPermissions` - obviously this means to repair the permissions
- `/` - act on the whole file system

If you can't get into Snow Leopard, you might be able to get into single-user mode by holding <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on boot

You can run Disk Utility from within Snow Leopard but whether it can repair it will depend on what's wrong.

You can do a Repair Permissions on any disk, or a Repair Disk on any disk which is not your startup disk. If you need to do a Repair Disk, you will need to do that from your CD and I think the 10.5 disk would be OK to use for a Repair Disk when booted from, it may not do a Repair Permissions though.

It's worth trying the Repair Permissions first from Snow Leopard. That solves a lot of issues

Comment: He's in the OS, otherwise he couldn't have run Onyx.

Comment: The reason I asked was because I'd have expected him to be able to run Disk Utility from within Snow Leopard rather than from the install CD.

Comment: I didn't even think to run Disk Utility from within Snow Leopard, honestly. I assumed I wouldn't be able to operate on a mounted filesystem.

Comment: Ah, yeah you can run it from within Snow Leopard but whether it can repair it will depend on what's wrong.  You can do a Repair Permissions on any disk, or a Repair Disk on any disk which is not your startup disk.  If you need to do a Repair Disk, you will need to do it from your CD and I think the 10.5 disk will be fine for the lower level stuff.  It's worth trying the Repair Permissions first from Snow Leopard though.  That solves a lot of issues.